# SceneBuilder Cannot Save

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, jetbrains-ide

I am using Jetbrains with Scenebuilder, I have project connected to repository using Gitlab.

In Jetbrains it seem everything is ok, however when I use Scenebuilder and try and save I get the error ava.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: (project location)

Comment: I don't use or know much of Girlab but sounds like a permissions issue to me. Do you have write permissions?

Comment: I dont know why I would not. I used netbeans for another project and it worked fine

Comment: You are using an IntelliJ plugin for this?

Comment: By default i see there is a git plugin but i did not add my own no